# How to mock Abstract class method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I need to test a class that extends an abstract class and uses it protected method. Here is the code:

```
public class DataDaoImpl extends SuperDao<CustomClass> 
{
   public List<Long> findAllbyId(Long productId)
   {
      Session session = getCurrentSession();
      .......
      //Rest of code
   }
}
```

and here is the code of abstract class:

```
public abstract class SuperDao<T>
{
    protected final Session getCurrentSession() 
     {  
       return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
     }
}
```

Now how should I write unit test for `DataDaoImpl` and should mock session in `Session session = getCurrentSession();`?

I have tried different solutions on Stackoverflow but I am still not able to mock it and get session mock.

I have tried using mocking `getcurrentSession()` as suggested in answer with following code:

```
@Test
public void testDataDaoImpl()
{
SessionFactory mockedSessionFactory = Mockito.mock(SessionFactory.class);
Session mockedSession = Mockito.mock(Session.class); 
Mockito.when(mockedSessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(mockedSession);   
DataDaoImpl DDI_Instance = new DataDaoImpl((long) 120);
DDI_Instance.findAllbyId(Long productId);
}
```

But still `session.getCurrentSession()` fails.

Comment: can you mock `SessionFactory` and its `getCurrentSession` instead of `SuperDao`'s `getCurrentSession`

Comment: Mocking private/protected or other invisible methods is bad idea. You may consider refactor you code and use delegation instead of inheritance.

Comment: @ talex Refactoring code is not an option for now. So can not do it.

Comment: @lsank I have edited question with suggested solution. Can you please have a look as I still get error with my test.

Comment: @AbhijeetPanwar what are you actually trying to test here? It doesn't make sense to mock `Session` or `SessionFactory`. It doesn't even make sense to mock `DataDaoImpl` in this case. What is the purpose of your test? If the test breaks, what would it mean, i.e. what could have happened to make that test fail (regardless of what was mocked)?

Comment: @Kayaman  My test case throws nullpointerexception at Session session = getCurrentSession(); line. There is more code in the method later and In the following code there is more code which needs to be tested. I am new to unit testing so  please let me know if I am doing some blunder with the unit testing.

Comment: @AbhijeetPanwar I just wanted to make sure you're not making a useless test. If `findAllById()` has extra functionality, it might be a poorly designed method (it's certainly not designed to be easily testable). Your alternatives are to inject the session somehow (e.g. reflection or so), or run the test in an environment where a session is available.

Comment: @Kayaman I totally understand that its a really poorly designed method but for now I can not refactor the code. So Is there a way to pass that line somehow?

Comment: @AbhijeetPanwar I gave you the alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

As `DataDaoImpl` extends `SuperDao`, method `getCurrentSession` inherently becomes a part of `DataDaoImpl` and you should avoid mocking the class being tested.

What you need to do is, mock `SessionFactory` and return mocked object when `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` is called. With that `getCurrentSession` in `DataDaoImpl` will return the mocked object.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I have tried it and added it to question details. I am new to JUnit so Can you please have a look at it.

Comment: Can you paste little detailed version of you abstract class and implementation class. Are you sure you are getting session as null or some other related function? Prima facie your test looks ok to me. Did you try to print it before using further in your class?

Comment: Yes. I am sure that session is null. I have tried debugging the test case and it  reaches SuperDao's  getCurrentSession method and throws exception on  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

Comment: @AbhijeetPanwar: What you also need to do is to inject the mock into your `DataDaoImpl` class. Currently there is no relation between those two.